# How to get out of grayed-out screen in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

There seems to be no way to submit a bug report unless you pay a lot for your account, so I'll post here in hopes of getting dev eyeballs.

I was just starting to poke around, having been given admin access by the account manager.  I dismissed a help screen or wizard of some kind... and the screen stayed grayed out.  I can interact with the search bar and the options on the left, but the main, white part of the screen remains grayed out and inaccessible.

Things I've tried:

- Refreshing the page
- hard cache reset
- Launching every wizard and help system I can find then dismissing them
- Logging out and in
- Clearing all cookies and local storage
- Using a different browser

The only thing that has worked is to go in and temporary remove the '.active-wizard' class on the main div.app-layout-content using Chrome's debugging tools, which lets me do work during the session, but reloading the page brings me right back to the grayed-out mode.

I'm guessing this condition is rare since I cant' find any mention online, but it's very annoying.

[image: My screen, all grayed out]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yonatan from JFrog R&D here

The bug is caused due to an edge case, where one of the projects onboarding flags failed to submit.

This bug will be fixed on next minor release.

You can quickly win this by doing the following:
On your browser console paste the command below and refresh the page.

*no important data will be affected, so no worries

```
window.store.dispatch('onboardingProcess/RESET_USER_ONBOARDING')
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with version **7.38.10**.
with window.store.dispatch('onboardingProcess/RESET_USER_ONBOARDING')
I get back an **undefined** as **return value**.

I removed the corresponding entry **content** and gave admin rights to another user.
The new user does not have the issue.
It works for the admin at least temporarily.

[image: css]

```css
.app-layout-wrapper .app-layout-content[data-v-2db44934]:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    transition: opacity .2s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, please use this command store.dispatch('common/onboardingProcess/RESET_USER_ONBOARDING')

it will solve the issue on the root user as well